# Extracting comma separated string values from a Query and assign them to different variables on Delphi 4

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to split a comma separated string from a Query and assign each one in a different variable:

```
qValidation.Close;
qValidation.SQL.Clear;
qValidation.SQL.Add('SELECT VALUE FROM PARAMETER WHERE CODPARAMETER = ''XYM'' ');
qValidation.Open;
```

The String I get from this Code (VALUE) is '***12.5,45.3,33.5,67.9***'

I want to get each value and assign them in a different variable, i.e:

```
X1 = 12.5
X2 = 45.3
X3 = 33.5
X4 = 67.9
```

These variables must be **float type**

I've read that you can use a TStringList but I don't find a Delphi4 clear way for me

Comment: Just to be clear, you have confirmed that TStringList is not part of the Delphi 4 libraries?

Comment: @SamM Obviously not. I think TStrings has been around since Delphi 1 - remember that the lines and items properties of TMemo and TComboBox use TStrings sub classes. TStringList was definitely in Delphi 3, the first version I used in 1997.

Comment: @SamM I've confirmed that TStringList exists in Delphi 4, but I don't get an understandable way to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delphi 4 library has the necessary functionality. This is `TStrings.CommaText` of unit [Classes](https://github.com/Starina123/AllDelphiSource/blob/aa3b7da380760df3e6350d4fc2c2f395552f2e6f/Delphi%204/VCL/CLASSES.PAS#L425).

`TStrings` is an abstract class, so must use `TStringList`

```
program ProjectTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

var
  vList: TStrings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  vList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    vList.CommaText := '12.5,45.3,33.5,67.9';

    for i := 0 to vList.Count - 1 do
      Writeln(vList[i]);
  finally
    vList.Free;
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

`TStringList` is declared in the `Classes` unit.  It has a `CommaText` property, which will parse the input text into its `Strings[]` property.  For each individual string, you can convert it to `Extended` using the `StrToFloat()` function in the `SysUtils` unit, and then assign that value to a `Single`/`Double` variable as needed.